# Swift3 Migration issues

Tags: swift, swift3, nslayoutconstraint

Getting error:

> Expression type '[NSLayoutConstraint?]' is ambiguous without more context"

After migrating from Swift2.2 to Swift3.

```
    let consAry = [emailBottom,pwrdBottom]

    var i : Int = Int(0)
    for constraint: NSLayoutConstraint in consAry {
        if ((i > 2) && (screenHeight <= 568)){
            padding = 10
        }
        constraint.constant = padding
        i = i + 1

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here type of `consAry` is `[NSLayoutConstraint?]` means it contains `optional` object of type `NSLayoutConstraint` and with for loop you are explicitly saying its type to `NSLayoutConstraint` means `non-optional`, so either remove that and inside the loop unwrapped the optional value or use `flatMap` on `consAry` with for loop.

**Option 1: Remove explicit specification with for loop**

```
for constraint in consAry {
    if ((i > 2) && (screenHeight <= 568)){
        padding = 10
    }
    constraint?.constant = padding        
    i = i + 1
}
```

**Option 2: Optional Wrapping using if let**

```
for constraint in consAry {
    if ((i > 2) && (screenHeight <= 568)){
        padding = 10
    }
    if let currentConstraint = constraint {
        currentConstraint.constant = padding
    }
    i = i + 1
}
```

**Option 3: Use `flatMap` on consAry**

```
for constraint in consAry.flatMap ({ $0 }) {
    if ((i > 2) && (screenHeight <= 568)){
        padding = 10
    }
    constraint.constant = padding
    i = i + 1
}
```

**Note:** You are using `i` for indexing here, so instead of that use [`enumerated()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1687832-enumerated) with for loop.

```
for (i, constraint) in consAry.flatMap ({ $0 }).enumerated() {
    if ((i > 2) && (screenHeight <= 568)){
        padding = 10
    }
    constraint.constant = padding
}
```

Comment: getting error for the last code- cannot assign to value: 'i' is a let constant

Comment: @ThripthiHaridas Remove that line now there is no need in each iteration of loop its value change automatically. Also there is no need to declare remove line `var i : Int = Int(0)`.